# Coordinates based on camera in Three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

This could be a very fundamental question. but i am straggling to understand. I am creating a scene using Three.js. The camera is as follows

`var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 85, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );` 
`camera.position.z = 5;`

Can anyone please explain what would be range of x and y based these values.
i found that -8>=x>=8 and -4>=Y>=4. but how this values are calculated? I am straggling to get the basics. If you could also point to some good article, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are x and y in your question ?

Comment: X, Y are coordinates of the scene. Since i am creating a 2D scene so z remains constant. I found that if objects.position.x=-8 takes the object to left. and objects.position.y takes it to the right.

Answer (score 2):

I take your question to mean to ask what is the range of x,y coordinates in world space that will still be visible to a perspective camera.

Before that can be answered, you must first understand what a modern 3D rendering pipeline is doing underneath the hood. Essentially, you can think it of as a bunch of matrix transforms that transforms an object first to the world space, then from the world space to screen space.

One key ingredient is the view-projection matrix which converts a world space coordinate [x,y,z] into "almost" screen space [x,y,z,w] and then the x,y,z are divided by w to get [x/w,y/w,z/w]. The resultant coordinate system have x = -1 as your left side of screen and x = +1 as your right side of screen, y = -1 as bottom of your screen and y = +1 as top of your screen.

As you can probably guess, the perspective camera is responsible for calculating that view-projection matrix for you (probably, I dont use Three.JS). Another nice property of matrix is that you can find its inverse. That is, the inverse of view-projection matrix takes "almost" screen space and convert it back to the world space. So, to answer the question, you can plug in [-1,-1,z] as the bottom left of the screen and transform it by the inverse of view-projection matrix and do the /w division, that will give you the world coordinate of x,y that will make the object appear at the bottom left of screen.

In pseudo code, it looks something like this:

```
 vec3.toWorldSpace = function(out, v3, viewProjectionMatrix){
    var invViewProj = mat4.inverse(vec3._m, viewProjectionMatrix);
    var m = invViewProj;
    vec3.transformByMat(out, v3, m);
    var w = m[3] * x + m[7] * y + m[11] * z + m[15]; // required for perspective divide
    if (w !== 0){
        var invW = 1.0/w;
        out[0] *= invW;
        out[1] *= invW;
        out[2] *= invW;
    }

    return out;
};
```

Comment: Thanks WaclawJasper for your explanation. I know the  coordinate varies between [-1,-1,z] to [1,1,z] but i trying to understand how this get effected by camera setting.

Answer (score 0):

Well after some trial and error i found that Three.js actually takes Objects.position.X as world coordinate.

Xp= X/(ar*Z*tan(angle/2))

Yp=Y/(Z*tan(angle/2))

All three.js gurus, please correct me if i am wrong.